# Trying to get around this Webservice call from Android using AsycTask

Tags: android, authentication, android-activity, crash

I am a fairly beginner in Android Development. I am developing an application that extensively relays on Webservice calls. First screen takes username and password and validates the user by calling the Webservice.  If U/P is valid, then I need to fire up the 2nd activity. In that 2nd activity, I need to do 3 calls. But I haven't gotten to the 2nd part yet. In fact, I haven't completed the full coding yet. But I wanted to test if the app is working as far as I've come through.

When calling webserivce, I am showing alert dialog. But the app is crashing somewhere. 
The LoginActivity shows up. When I enter U/P and press Login Button, it crashes.

My classes:

TaskHandler.java

```
 public class TaskHandler {

private String URL;
private User userObj;
private String results;
private JSONDownloaderTask task; ;

public TaskHandler( String url, User user) {
    this.URL = url;
    this.userObj = user;
}

public String handleTask() {
    Log.d("Two", "In the function");
    task = new JSONDownloaderTask();
    Log.d("Three", "In the function");
    task.execute(URL);
    return results;
}

private class JSONDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private String username;// = userObj.getUsername();
    private String password; //= userObj.getPassword();

    public  HttpStatus status_code;

    public JSONDownloaderTask() {
        Log.d("con", "Success");
        this.username = userObj.getUsername();
        this.password = userObj.getPassword();

        Log.d("User" + this.username , " Pass" + this.password);
    }

    private AsyncProgressActivity progressbar = new AsyncProgressActivity();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressbar.showLoadingProgressDialog();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        final String url = params[0]; //getString(R.string.api_staging_uri) + "Authenticate/";

        // Populate the HTTP Basic Authentitcation header with the username and password
        HttpAuthentication authHeader = new HttpBasicAuthentication(username, password);
        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.setAuthorization(authHeader);
        requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        // Create a new RestTemplate instance
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());

        try {
            // Make the network request
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), url);

            ResponseEntity<Message> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders), Message.class);
            status_code =  response.getStatusCode();
            return response.getBody().toString();
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {

            status_code = e.getStatusCode();
            return new Message(0, e.getStatusText(), e.getLocalizedMessage(), "error").toString();
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName()  ,e.getLocalizedMessage());
            return "Unknown Exception";
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        progressbar.dismissProgressDialog();


        switch ( status_code ) {
        case UNAUTHORIZED:
            result =  "Invalid username or passowrd"; break;
        case ACCEPTED:
            result = "Invalid username or passowrd" + status_code; break;
        case OK:
            result = "Successful!"; break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

AsycProgressActivity.java

```
public class AsyncProgressActivity  extends Activity {

protected static final String TAG = AsyncProgressActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private boolean destroyed = false;

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    destroyed = true;
}

public void showLoadingProgressDialog() {
    Log.d("Here", "Progress");
    this.showProgressDialog("Authenticating...");
    Log.d("Here", "afer p");
}

public void showProgressDialog(CharSequence message) {
    Log.d("Here", "Message");
    if (progressDialog == null) {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    }
    Log.d("Here", "Message 2");

    progressDialog.setMessage(message);
    progressDialog.show();
}

public void dismissProgressDialog() {
    if (progressDialog != null && !destroyed) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
}
```

LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends AsyncProgressActivity implements OnClickListener {

Button login_button;
HttpStatus status_code;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    login_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    login_button.setOnClickListener(this);
    ViewServer.get(this).addWindow(this); 
}

public void onDestroy() {  
    super.onDestroy();  
    ViewServer.get(this).removeWindow(this);  
}  

public void onResume() {  
    super.onResume();  
    ViewServer.get(this).setFocusedWindow(this);  
}  

public void onClick(View v) {
    if ( v.getId() == R.id.btnLogin ) {

        User userobj = new User();
        String result;
        userobj.setUsername( ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.username)).getText().toString());
        userobj.setPassword(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.password)).getText().toString() );


        TaskHandler handler = new TaskHandler(getString(R.string.api_staging_uri) + "Authenticate/", userobj);
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "One");
        result = handler.handleTask();
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "After two");
        Utilities.showAlert(result, LoginActivity.this);
    }
}
```

Utilities.java

```
public class Utilities {

public static void showAlert(String message, Context context) {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Login");

    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(message)
                      .setCancelable(false)
                      .setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            //dialog.cancel();
                        }
                       });
    alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(drawable.ic_dialog_alert);

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show(); 
}
 }
```

**EDIT: More info**

I tried to add Logging step by step to see where its crashing. It looks like its crashing here. Because its not showing the log message after this.

```
        Log.d("Here", "Message");
    if (progressDialog == null) {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    }
    Log.d("Here", "Message 2");
```

`Message 2` is not showing up in the log, but `Message` shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is your `handleTask` method:

```
public String handleTask() {
    Log.d("Two", "In the function");
    task = new JSONDownloaderTask();
    Log.d("Three", "In the function");
    task.execute(URL);
    return results;
}
```

You are kicking off an AsyncTask which will populate the `results` variable in another thread **when the task is finished**. However, you are returning this value right away and immediately using it to build an AlertDialog. This variable probably has not been populated by the background thread yet and may still be null.

EDIT: You probably shouldn't call `showAlert` in `onClick`. Instead, you should call it in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: Pls see my Edit. The issue seems to be in ProgressDialog. Not sure if it has anything to do with the solution you proposed.

Comment: I think there are a number issues at play here. First of all, why is the progress dialog in its own activity? I could just be a member of the LoginActivity. That is the "current activity" whose context you should be passing to the ProgressDialog's constructor instead of ProgressDialog(this) - where 'this' is the AsyncProgressActivity that you've manually created yourself.

Second...you are definitely using the result of the Asynctask before its done processing in a background thread. This can product very unpredictable results.

Comment: Thats a good point. I will try to restructure the files to get it under main activity and update how it goes.

Comment: Removing the Activity for progressDialog solved the problem. Thanks!